# escape character in Tera Term macro string?

Tags: macros, terminal

I'm writing a Tera Term macro and I need to assign a string variable that contains `'` and `"`. I've looked around on various tutorials but couldn't find mention of how to do this, so hopefully it exists.

These string variables don't work:

```
hello = "command1 argument1 "foo/hello/world.txt""
world = 'command2 argument2 'bar/hello/world.txt''
```

The syntax error given:
[image]

---

Through experimentation I've figured out that I can mix and match single and double quotes in order to allow one or the other, but not both.

These string variables work:

```
foo = "command1 argumen1t 'foo/hello/world.txt'"
bar = 'command2 argument2 "bar/hello/world.txt"'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is an escape character for strings (I searched and didn't find anything on this), however I found a way to get around this. I'm not saying it's the right way, but at least it might work for your situation.

To send quotes in, I used the ASCII value feature of [sendln](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/macro/command/sendIn.html) (actual documentation in the [send](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/macro/command/send.html) function)

```
FILE1='foo/hello/world.txt'
FILE2='bar/hello/world.txt'
sendln 'command1 argument1 ' 34 FILE1 34
sendln 'command2 argument2 ' 39 FILE2 39
```

Testing the above macro yielded the following entered into the terminal

```
command1 argument1 "foo/hello/world.txt"
command2 argument2 'bar/hello/world.txt'
```